# Alarm clock only works for one scheduled day does not work for multiple scheduled day

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am working on alarm clock for my project in android and i am new to programming.
My code works fine for one schedule day only what I mean by that is it will work fine when I schedule for Mon 12 but when I schedule it for Mon Tue Sat 12 it does not work.

```
 public class AlarmClock extends Activity {
        private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
        private TimePicker alarmTimePicker;
        AlarmManager alarmManager;
        private EditText descriptionText;
        private static MainActivity inst;
        private CheckBox checkBox1,checkBox2,checkBox3,checkBox4,checkBox5,checkBox6,checkBox7;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_clock);
            alarmTimePicker = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.alarmTimePicker);
            alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            checkBox1= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sundayCheckBox);
            checkBox2= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.mondayCheckBox);
            checkBox3= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.tuesdayCheckBox);
            checkBox4= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.wednesdayCheckBox);
            checkBox5= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.thursdayCheckBox);
            checkBox6= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.fridayCheckBox);
            checkBox7= (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.saturdayCheckBox);




        }
        public void save (View v){
            if (checkBox1.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(1);
            }

            if (checkBox2.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(2);
            }

            if (checkBox3.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(3);
            }

            if (checkBox4.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(4);
            }

            if (checkBox5.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(5);
            }

            if (checkBox6.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(6);
            }

            if (checkBox7.isChecked())
            {
                activityToPerform(7);
            }



        }
        private void activityToPerform(int week)
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "Alarm On");
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, week);
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmTimePicker.getCurrentMinute());
            descriptionText= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.descriptionEditText);
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadcast.class);
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, myIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        }
```

Comment: The second parameter in the `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` method is a request code that needs to be unique for each of your alarms.

Comment: @MikeM thank you once again.